# Как передать POST в модальное окно?

Tags: javascript

Есть форма с одним полем и модальное окно bootstrap-4. Подскажите как передать данные с формы методом POST в модальное окно? Если можно с примером кода. Гугл не помог.

Comment: в пределах страницы вам просто нужно JS скрипт написать который скопирует информацию в модальное окно в нужный селектор. Никакие запросы делать не надо)))

Comment: Нужно передать именно данные с формы (поле выбора select). Я понимаю что это JS но его я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

если у вас jquery  там есть serialize метод
если нативный js ч то то типа такова можно

```
var serializable = function (formId) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);


    var result = {};
    var elements = Array.from(form.getElementsByTagName('*'));
    var data = elements.filter(function(element){
        return element.hasAttribute('serialize');
    }).map(function(element){
        if (!element.name) {
            throw new Error ('set name attribute to element! ' 
            + element.nodeName + (element.id.length ? ' (with id ' + element.id + ') ' : ' (with className ' + element.className + ')')
            );
        }
        return element.name  + ':' + element.value;
    }).forEach(function(element) {
        var key = element.trim().split(':')[0];
        var value = element.trim().split(':')[1];
        result[key] = value || null;
    });

    return JSON.stringify(result);
}

form id="form">

        <div>
            <select name="type2" id="se45" serialize>
                <option value="v1">Вариант 1</option>
                <option value="v2">Вариант 2</option>
                <option value="v3">Вариант 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input serialize type="text" name="tect45">
        </div>

        <div>
            <input serialize type="password"  name="password" class="clasNemr234">
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <input  type="checkbox" onchange="selecteg('female')" name="isold">
                <span>female</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input  type="checkbox"  onchange="selecteg('male')" name="isold">
                <span>male</span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" serialize name="gender" id="dww"></span>
        </div>

        <button type="button" onclick="send('form')">send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: А как потом вывести данные в окне?

Comment: есть форма 

<form action="?" method="post">
<select class="btn" name="name" size="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>

кнопку в ней нужно заменить на 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Запустить модальное окно
</button>

для запуска окна и передать в него данные формы

Answer (score 0):

Вот принцип работы. Выведет все значения инпутов в поле с классом text .

```js
var $formname = $('#formname') // тут указываем класс или id формы.
var $outBlock = $('.text') // тут блок в который вывести содержимое надо

$formname.on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $outBlock.empty();
  $.each($(this).serializeArray(),function (i,v) {
  $outBlock.append(v.value+'<br>')
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="formname">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <select name="optionsName" id="">
        <option value="text1">text1</option>
        <option value="text2">text2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<div class="text">
Тут будет вывод из input
</div>
```